# Need help with notation. Slightly off topic.

Tags: notation

I am designing a coffee cup and I want to check the notation, (L-R order, and operator).

What is the best to express [these quotes?](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Theorem.html)
$$\text{Coffee}_{\text{Strong}} \iff \text{Theorem}{}^{\left[\text{Alfred Renyi}\right]}$$
$$\text{Coffee}_{\text{Weak}} \iff \text{Lemmas}{}^{\text{[Paul Turan]}}$$

Alfred Renyi: mathworld.wolfram.com/Theorem.html
Paul Turan: mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemma.html
Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: oeis.org

I want the cup to look professional, even if I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think it's more correct to say $$\text{Mathematician}:\text{Coffee}\to \text{Results}\\\text{Strong}\mapsto \text{Theorems}\\\text{Weak} \mapsto \text{Lemmas}$$i.e. that $\text{Mathematician}$ is a function from the set of coffees to the set of results.